# use printf function in inline asm on gcc

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly

I want to test inline asm capabilty  on gcc.
So, I type and compile following code on ubuntu 12.04  64-bit 
but system shows ''segmentation fault" on screen when it runs.
I don't have any idea what causes the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char Format[]="Hello world %d\n";
int main()
{
    asm
    (
        "movl $3,4(%esp);"
        "movl $Format,(%esp);"
        "call printf;"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you guys for helping me a program newbie.
I use Code::blocks as IDE to write this code.  I had tried to use 64-bit registers such like %rdx, but logs of Build messages shows "  Error: bad register name `%rdx' " when compiling the code. I think this means the gcc  invoked by Code::blocks is 32-bit version, hence it can't recognize those registers.
I modify the code to reserve the stack space

```
#include <stdio.h>
char Format[]="Hello world %d\n";
int main()
{
    asm
    (
        "subl $8,%esp;"         //I  don't know  $4, $8, $12, $16, $20 which is correct
                                        //but I had tried them all but results are still  ''segmentation fault."
        "movl $3,4(%esp);"
        "movl $Format,(%esp);"
        "call printf;"
        "movl %ebp,%esp;"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

and even use -m32 as compiler option, but it still shows ''segmentation fault ".

thanks again for who helps.

Comment: Watch your calling conventions. I believe the first operand needs to be `eax`.

Comment: Or, compile with `-m32` and don't give a crap about the calling convention...

Comment: To move something into `%rdx` you should use `movq`. Does it print the text before it segfaults?

Comment: You are incorrectly restoring the stack after the call to `printf`. See my updated answer for some additions on how to call `printf` in 64-bit mode and a working 32-bit example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System V ABI for x64 mandates that the first six integer/pointer arguments to a function should go in registers `%rdi`, `%rsi`, `%rdx`, `%rcx`, `%r8` and `%r9`. The stack is used to pass further arguments. It also requres that when calling functions with variable number of arguments (like `printf`), `%rax` should be set to the total number of floating-point arguments passed in the `XMM` registers. The right sequence to call `printf()` in your case is:

```
xorl %eax, %eax
movl $Format, %edi
movl $3, %esi
call printf
```

`%rax` should be set to `0` since no floating-point arguments are being passed. This code also uses the fact that VA of initialised data usually lies somewhere in the first 4 GiB and thus shorter 32-bit instructions are used. Of course `printf` will still examine the full content of `%rdi` to determine where the format string is located in memory.

Your code uses the 32-bit calling convention and should theoretically work if cross-compiled as 32-bit with `-m32` but you should first reserve stack space for the arguments using something like `subl $20, %esp` and restore it after the call with `addl %20, %esp`, otherwise you are either overwriting the stack of `main()` or `ret` will pick the wrong return address. Here is a fully working (tested) C/asm code that compiles and run in 32-bit mode:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char Format[] = "Hello world, %d\n";

int main (void)
{
   asm
   (
      // Make stack space for arguments to printf
      "subl $8, %esp\n"
      "movl $3, 4(%esp)\n"
      "movl $Format, (%esp)\n"
      "call printf\n"
      // Clean-up the stack
      "addl $8, %esp\n"
   );
   return 0;
}

$ gcc -m32 -o test.x test.c
$ ./test.x
Hello world, 3
```

Remark: I use `\n` instead of `;` at the end of each assembly line only to improve the readability of the compiler assembly output - it is irrelevant to the correctness of the code.

Comment: Beware of _register clobbering_ ... the above works for a simple demo program. If you've got a complex piece of code where you're planning to use inline assembly that contains `call` instructions, then you need to save/restore a few registers (one or all of `edi`, `esi`, `ebp` and `ebx`) around the `call`, and declare all other registers clobbered. Otherwise, the compiler may assume register contents to persist over the function call where that would change the contents.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions
I found this wiki page quite useful to solve these kind of questions.

Comment: You forgot to declare clobbers for EAX, ECX, and EDX, not to mention XMM0..7 and ST0..7.  (And k0..7 if AVX-512 is available).  It's hard to safely call a function from GNU C inline asm.  See [Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37502841)  GNU C "Basic" asm statements (no `:` operands and clobbers) inside functions (except `__attribute__((naked))`) are a bad idea.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Answer (score 4):

Try first to look at a normal C program and see what asm it gives (you can get it by using `gcc -S`).

Then, identify the part of ASM which is needed for the `printf` call and reproduce it in your original program.

What you have here is a [calling](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html) [convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) error.