# Calling assembly function from C with parameters

Tags: c, assembly, parameter-passing, inline-assembly, calling-convention

A friend of mine sent me an assembly function with a description like this:

> Function Foo 
> Parameters: 
> EAX -> unsigned 32 bit integer 
> CL -> unsigned 16 bit integer 
> RDI -> unsigned 64 bit integer

Now I need to call this function from my C program and I solved the problem by doing this:

```
asm volatile ("         \n\t\
    mov eax, 0          \n\t\
    mov cl, 1           \n\t\
    mov rdi, 0x120000   \n\t\
    call foo            \n\t\
");
```

Which works but is a bit ugly and inconvenient. I thought about wrapping this inline asm in a function but I don't like it as a solution. I tried to declare the function as extern:

```
extern foo(uint32_t eax, uint16_t cl, uint64_t rdi);
```

And with this line, the compiler does not complain at all but the parameters are all messed up. Is there a way to simplify the calling of this function with extern? If not how do I have to modify the parameters to make it works with this technique?

Comment: Change parameter passing to conform to whatever ABI you are using. On linux that would be the sysv one. Pass your 3 arguments in `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`. See for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI)

Comment: @Jester Ok, since I'm using gcc I'll switch to these three registers that you've listed. If you post this comment as a answer I'll check it as correct

Comment: Note that you cannot overwrite random registers in an `asm` statement.  The compiler expects that all register's contents will be preserved by inline assembly.

Comment: @Delarosa if you overwrite registers in inline assembly be sure to include them in the clobbers list. See more at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: `CL` is an 8-bit register, not 16-bit.  The corresponding 16-bit register is `CX`.  You should check with your friend to clarify what was intended.

Comment: 100% agreed with Jester: if you want to call from C, write your asm to follow a standard calling convention that the compiler already knows how to call.  x86-64 System V is nice.  Do *not* use inline asm, especially not in 64-bit mode; it's a massive pain and very hard to do safely, and causes a lot of inefficiency.  (e.g. [Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37503773))  Compilers are good at making function calls based on a prototype.