# How can I call a function in inline assembly from C

Tags: c, assembly, inline-assembly

I am currently playing around with in-line simply and I've gotten a bit stuck. I have managed to call a function with no parameters but when it comes to calling one with two parameters I get stuck.

My code below should call a function `(add)` that adds to predefined numbers together and it should  call a second one `(add parameter)` with two parameters which should be added together.

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int c = 4;
  int d = 5;
  void add() {
      int result = 1 + 2;
      printf("Result: %d\n", result);
  }

  void add_parameter(int a, int b) {
      int result = a + b;
      printf("Result: %d\n", result);
  }


int main()
{
       __asm__ __volatile__ ( "call add" );

    //    __asm__ __volatile__(
    //     "mov     eax, offset c"
    //     "push    eax"
    //     "mov     eax, offset d"
    //     "push    eax"
    //     "call add_parameter"
    //     "pop     ebx"
    //     "pop     ebx"
    //    );

    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "mov eax, offset c" );
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "push eax" );
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "mov eax, offset d" );
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "push eax" );
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "call add_parameter" );
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "pop ebx" );
    __asm__ __volatile__ ( "pop ebx" );

    return 0;
}
```

My problem at the moment is that when I try to compile the program I get an error that says

```
p_function.c:31: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
p_function.c:33: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
```

In my program I've tried two approaches one being one single ASM call with the whole ASM code in it and one where I had split each line into its own asm call.

Unfortunately I am not sure which one of these approaches is correct let alone the most effective but I get the same error regardless of which approach I use.
How can I fix this problem and call the function `add_parameter`

Thanks

Comment: Even if you used AT&T syntax (or used `gcc -masm=intel` to get it to read this as Intel syntax) to fix the error message you're getting now, it wouldn't be safe to use Basic asm (no constraints); you modify register values, and so could the called function.

Comment: You need to write %eax instead of eax.

Comment: I added [Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37502841) to the list of duplicates as an example of the clobber declarations necessary for calling a function  to be safe.  (i.e. describe the calling convention via the clobber list).  That question is for x86-64 so the actual arg-passing is different (in regs instead of the stack).  Your entire approach of using Basic Asm statements inside a function is totally flawed (always use Extended asm), separate from the Intel vs. AT&T syntax mixup.