# Ensuring x64 compliance of custom ASM-function in clang-cl

Tags: c++, x86-64, inline-assembly, calling-convention, clang-cl

For my custom compiled native x64 JIT-code, I have certain instrinsic functions. A lot of them are just called from my code, thus I will generate with my own compiler. Some of them however are directly called from c++-code, and thus I want to have them be compiled inside a static-lib, so that they can at least be linked statically, if not inlined.

I need to use inline-assembly for those functions, as they perform actions that cannot be expressed in regular C++, like setting a non-volatile register from a function-input. However, the function itself must behave like a regular x64-function - it needs a prolog/epilogue, and it must have the necessary unwind-information to support stack-traces and exception-handling. Thus I cannot use MSVC (which is my native compiler), so I decided to make a static lib with clang-cl in Visual Studio instead. The best I got so far is the following:

```
void interruptEntry(void* pState, const char* pAddress)
{
    __asm
    {
        // load state into RBX
        mov rbx,rcx
        // load callstack-top into RDI
        mov rax,[rbx]
        mov rdi,[rax]

        // call address
        call rdx
    };
}
```

This will generate the proper prolog, epilogue and all required unwind-information. However, it critically lacks the 32 bytes of shadow-space that are necessary by x64 (which pAddress needs to be called by):

```
Acclimate Engine.dll!interruptEntry(void *, const char *):
 push        rdi  
 push        rbx  
 mov         rbx,rcx  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rbx]  
 mov         rdi,qword ptr [rax]  
 call        rdx  
 pop         rbx  
 pop         rdi  
 ret
```

Keep in mind, while this code is generated via clang-cl, the DLL is linked with MSVC. The static-lib is compiled with O2 (set from the VisualStudio-project page).

Things I've tried:

- Modifying RSP manually, with sub RSP,32. This results in a frame-pointer register being established, as the compiler will count this as a dynamic stack allocation. This adds too much overhead to make it worth using a statically compiled function in the first place
- Similarily, I could reference "pState" directly in asm (mov rbx,pState), this will cause the shadow-space to be added - but also, pState will then be copied onto the stack, and loaded into rbx from that stack location, instead of the register. This once again defeats the purpose of what I am doing here.
- Calling "pAddress" as a function-pointer directly, after the asm-block. This will still not result in any difference in code-gen
- Using normal asm(), or extended asm, in combination with "**attribute**((naked))". That will not generate the prolog/epilogue, which I can write myself - but then the unwind-information is missing. clang-cl seems to not understand any of the unwind-data directives, like .allocstack or .pushreg, resulting in a "error : unknown directive" - regardless of in which type of asm-block it's being used.

Is there any reason why the shadow-space is missing, and any way to get it there without adding any uncessary overhead like a frame-pointer (while still having unwind-information)? I'm also open for other suggestions - for example, if there is some intrinsic that let's me set those registers (while still compiling down to the one move), I would not need to use assembly (manipulating specific registers with global effect is the main reason I cannot write plain C++).

Comment: *MASM64* [can generate unwind information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/proc?view=msvc-170). Is that what you are looking for? Coupled with a totally handwritten set of assembly functions?

Comment: [More macros for generating unwinding information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170#unwind-helpers-for-masm).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thank you, I'll have a look at MASM64, if it fits my requirements better. For those specific functions, I wouldn't actually need to have them totally hand-written - inserting inline-assembly to extend regular code would be enough - but if it does what I want, that's also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making calls from inline asm is generally not well supported.  Avoid whenever possible.
The compiler only scans the inline asm block to see what registers are potentially clobbered; it doesn't assume that `call` instructions in asm are to functions that follow the standard calling convention for this target (otherwise why would you be using inline asm in the first place?)  So it's a huge pain to do it safely, same for x86-64 System V (*[Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502841/calling-printf-in-extended-inline-asm)* - using GNU C inline asm you also have to declare all the register clobbers yourself, as well as take care of the red-zone since there's no way to declare a clobber on that.)

Your idea of using inline asm to leave values in regs and block tail-call optimization is a good idea.  But the implementation in your self-answer with two separate `asm()` statements doesn't do anything to stop the compiler from stepping on RBX with the instructions it emits for code outside the `asm` statements.  A different compiler or version could easily break your code by picking RBX as a temporary instead of RAX when compiling that code between the asm statements.  (And since you didn't use `__attribute__((noinline))`, code from parent functions could be scheduled here.)

You can write it in a way that discourages the compiler from stepping on your registers.  Make those values needed in those registers after the call (as inputs to an empty `asm` statement), so the asm you want is the only efficient choice.  That makes it a lot less likely that this will break in practice.

```
class ExecutionStateJIT;
using Func = void ();

void interruptEntry_safer(ExecutionStateJIT& state, Func pAddress)
{
    register void *state_addr asm("rbx") = &state;
    // strict-aliasing violation, see alternate version that's safe without -fno-strict-aliasing
    register auto* pTemp asm("rdi") = * *((void***)&state);  // two derefs
    // register ... asm("rbx") is actually redundant since I also used specific-register constraints in the asm statement

    // request those vars in RDI and RBX respectively
    asm volatile("" :: "D"(pTemp), "b"(state_addr));  // make sure they're actually loaded before
    pAddress();  // this just uses a function-pointer arg that was already in a register, doesn't need to touch any others

    // prevent a tailcall which would restore RDI and RBX before calling
    asm volatile("" :: "D"(pTemp), "b"(state_addr));  // and still wanted in these call-preserved registers after
}
```

Using `register T foo asm("regname")` [local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) lets you ask for values in any of R8-R15 which don't have specific-register constraint letters, forcing an `"r"(var)` constraint to pick a specific register.  (And for many other ISAs, there aren't letters for any single registers.)  It's not actually needed here because the `"D"` and `"b"` constraints require RDI and RBX respectively.

[**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYgATKVpMGoZAFI9AIQuXSS%2BsgJ4BlRugDCqWgFcWDfaRuADJ4DJgAcr4ARpjEIADMAGykAA6oCoTODJ4%2BfgFpGU4CIWGRLDFxSXaYDkUMQgRMxAQ5vv4G9piOWQ1NBCUR0bEJyQqNza15HeP9oYPlw0kAlHao3sTI7BzIRgoKANTYql3edb0EmABSAJIAKmbx1hoAgt4ZJvsAYt4MyPsPABF9gA3VB4dD7CBLB5PZ5mF4AfQRTAIBGIeCip0wSKgDDBDFocyW0JeoPB%2B1CF2IxG8KQI2EExAAngiSHhgBAjiczo0Ljd7npEvsxijMKQvj8/ilnuh0MRMHsSXCAOyw/bq/ZMBQsCAWPQsVDA/bEKKqUgWACsGhhevhzw1Dv2IDtjo1IH%2Bej0xD1kIsiRFFyVrvV7ttegtJtUeuhjztLo1TFOqAAVPsUrdMCwUv94kDk1Ayehk8noYKA5gY2qE9rdZ6DUbiPhzRbrOHrRaATbPfHXc6XsGnR6vT6IOnMykg8HQ93w428NGbS8e2mZXKFQooYu4f3qywQV4UXRMLW9AvY0vlZ2ly8APQ3/aMNDrJjATD7NBZo/EfZEfYAa0wTBszWb9gSaA5Qn2AAlSwAA1NQYCEoIBa59lpH9UB/BA31EWhaDtO99iRFE0QxLEcQgPFQkJMJiX2QiUnlVEmWFJgqDfTBgUYCkqApAh9nwCFqLmO1CwpQRYhpOkGTRFkFDY2JOWOZBTh6XkrjuP1hXU8Vvl%2BFdZXlRU41VZd5WAPAxlifdyWTctkUMzUaz1SNoxzIE/XLLcHXMyyqU1JNUzHLMnJ1Fz8DcwF9lTfMIELYsS089TK2XO9guzKLYvikt0srdVCLwXj0HxYB9gEWgWIEN8sHlXiCGw/YaGIMYfzwNhUvvXyrO/AA6PrQpPVzPSWCkDiYRxvDECrjUwdAfnQYx%2BPeTZ9lQsQFEwt5ZuFFIukKvBkAAWi6/y0AYMZiCYSkIIYLC3y1PdyzYQQ4x3dUHv3IwnHoE8fRAac9E7T1RwzLMViHKI9QgeymEM4kYXy%2B8WCYADhXWN96swJkwA4eVNQmqaWNoVBYe2mJ%2BHlZdpUM9dN0eRGsMs/ZtDefitrGxrJTqTViFK%2BqUX2AB3LVNVoeVYZYyCmBmizuvFYqFQYHH%2BLCbbfyIbxkAQBDKsx5qOrTeUuMETUfyu2hcNoIWEAO7XBbWWgISMog8eQtbEOguD9nJkgcKm0JgGXD7QS%2Bo9fs9J0AaBvQQfHcG9Uh4GYbhvL6PvYwITGOgreFiShNuzGlHfKbDsYhVYi4p3MFlqkxqoKkTKvbdnjEylJNpelGTkhTiARC6DoIZFCS1AOlO5NTRX5LTy10yUDLXYyLyrdU3gDmz0Ay3N1%2BTbyNVXj4xDwEeTARQtN6BYjUXRTELgo5GWUPrU6LP3eGcf95gFPsEN9G020jb4gh0iCHTEhATAPVgA9X2AADm9kyC4BwBD7FUNAxIh1EiSCWD1A278A5f3BCkVMxdboxDTPiC4EIBbGEqlEbQXQloKQquKX89A2YHGJrDU28VlxiTsupBycp3Ien9OpV%2BAUiBBVBufaKEBcEnzPiWZOcoEZp32ISVGbAWDIBSCxG%2Bot2QMGevxYAk1LoSTJl0RMRc8REWRFfMit8ERQEPsAMI6AIBcGJJOdU6UhH5jkZ/BRSx0pbiDtqT6h4fphj0JHIc0dY5g3FAnKGSjiDw3pqo5GqMFDozutjXG90CZ4SJiTLAEIfaUzevPIyG5U6EXqkzFmLV2amyoFzLIPM%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%2BhkgFEyAIN9EhUjpAAwwAY37hiCmqLUCeEwvBtGA4%2BnkfQINDDiOGOwMwgPjpFM0NDCwMMWgfcS9gegUVooxfauVyDUHoMkPsYAyA/gWp6jEzk%2BAXYejJUsClVLiSMoSFwFlyplQWmgRoQViR4jcr0JIaQwrRWkHFYkC0PUBWcviBoflWnBWSC4MkGVV7OAKqVaQFVWgVgau1WsAgKRTjkEoMar84RWBbBQWgjBjHmP7FY%2BSwInG2ToACF24QuE%2B3SFC0OtQ9qx2kEFpdFIfqKMcHRdK6jnBPWnHs/xVAvEPP0e8yx%2BIbHISeD1dZUlni%2BOqoE7SmqlAUtKfFfESQPVoGSA0IkTl0DUHcrE9Ai06XQ1ytM8q/jKwmXxGE4kUT4nJOChk5IOTCnODxCoyNkz5n%2BPqq1dZiASBnP6sc0a3VJr9UoCMCYLg0CuBSpoLQG1EA7WhsdcwZkua3vOu9XQxwuaA2MAIEGiq9rw3eEjdG3N8bJ1JuxSm%2BheB032qzdyLYbqL32qLSWpkZatjYsrclvgdbG3Ntbe23NoWe3iH7VFpQMXR0gAU5OlA07bBFvnQypddRV3rr3Q9c9%2BbN07oBUApor5%2BIeYRBgw6gtpeC1CMVQWChDquO8Feri1Jb0c4fTUBHz63A4cCIhAjP7x3/rqIb83WQTfDFw7rp99RsMIbyHb2DAhej4a/ehpDTvcjvqw6hr3hGJAkfWJsfQKW0tGZxZwWjnmGM7Enb56B6meoaEhLgQgJBuPkZq5ZmlAyGsMqm8Jrg4ZEiJD0JyuTGhbt8sMJwZrIAK/qegcqSTGh4gWk5cqMveh4jDdlVtxV43au7fgAdkAtmcsnaO7EVzbBOAFa84nj4N3U%2BZsC%2BiYLBhKfhYkJF2Q0WR3Yt0NIBLTAkvVob6ljbQ%2BOBZbs6cMq%2BW6Mr6u6Vdfwn08QHK%2Bdyr/emCee1KpA9WwwDKimYqCQJWde3KnKGCGgegbeomg%2Bxm8qdgZmFmIBJeImA2C20msm8mN%2B62qBMe6BWBAmwq/m4qd2Uq0eo222tWKwGuGQLgkgQAA%3D%3D%3D) shows it works in GCC and clang (`-masm=ms` for GCC, and `-target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` for Clang.  As a bonus, this doesn't require very-recent Clang for `-masm=intel` to apply to asm statements, since the actual templates are empty.  The action is in the constraints, requiring the compiler to have both values in the registers we want, but without any

---

Your code also violates the strict-aliasing rule by pointing a `void **` at an object of a different type.  Only `[unsigned] char*` and pointers to objects declared with `__attribute__((may_alias))` can be pointed at arbitrary things in GNU C.  But for compat with MSVC, `clang-cl` probably enables `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

```
class ExecutionStateJIT;
using Func = void ();
void interruptEntry_safer_strict_aliasing(ExecutionStateJIT& state, Func pAddress)
{
    using voidp = void*;
    using aliasing_voidp = __attribute__((may_alias)) voidp;
    // aliasing_voidp is a pointer-to-void (e.g. 8 bytes on x86-64).
    // aliasing_voidp*  can be pointed at any object safely, to let us load a void*
    void *state_addr = &state;
    auto* pTemp = *(aliasing_voidp*)state_addr;  // like memcpy but alignment guaranteed because no __attribute__((aligned(1)))
    pTemp = *(aliasing_voidp*)pTemp;

    asm volatile("" :: "D"(pTemp), "b"(state_addr));  // make sure they're actually loaded before
    pAddress();  // this just uses a function-pointer arg that was already in a register, doesn't need to touch any others
    // prevent a tailcall which would restore RDI and RBX before calling
    asm volatile("" :: "D"(pTemp), "b"(state_addr));  // and still wanted in these call-preserved registers after
}
```

Both of these compile to the same asm as yours with current versions of GCC and clang, and the source is shorter and easier to read (if you know GNU C inline asm).  The point is that they will more reliably do so with future versions and even if inlined into other surrounding code.

```
interruptEntry_safer_strict_aliasing(ExecutionStateJIT&, void (*)()):
        push    rdi
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rcx               # state_addr
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rcx]   # first pTemp
        mov     rdi, QWORD PTR [rax]   # second value of pTemp
        call    rdx
# clang puts a NOP here for some reason
        add     rsp, 40
        pop     rbx
        pop     rdi
        ret
```

I didn't use `__attribute__((noinline))` on my versions since even in a use-case where they do inline into a caller (e.g. `-flto` link-time optimization), the asm statements hopefully convinces the compiler not to do something else with RBX or RDI in that window between the asm statement and the call, if it is moving code around to try to schedule it more efficiently.

Comment: Thank you! noinline was not needed, as the function is defined in a header, and used only in the MSVC-project (cant be possibly inlined then). I saw the "register" variable based syntax in some doc, but assumed it was only C since C++ retired the "register" keyword. The void-cast was just a workaround, until I move the type-definition into the new project (but yes, clang-cl uses no-strict alias - I violate that a lot actually though, since MSVC is fine with it).

Comment: On further attempts, I did find out that clang is happy with __asm blocks, as in my original code, and will scan registers there as well (though this cannot be compiled in godbolt, seems to only work on clang-cl). I'm assuming though, that this will also not guarantee registers are not overwritten, so I will be using local register variables to ensure this.

Comment: @Juliean: I included the strict-aliasing-safe part mostly for future readers who might be using GCC or mainline clang (not clang-cl, and without `-fno-strict-aliasing`) since we ended up using purely GNU C inline asm, no MSVC / clang-cl / clang `-fasm-blocks` stuff.  And partly out of curiosity to see what it would look like when the aliased object is itself a pointer, rather than just an `int`.  It would be easy to mix this up and make the ultimate `void` object may_alias but the pointer object still non-aliasing.

Comment: @Juliean: With mainline clang, the relevant option is `-fasm-blocks` for `__asm { }`.  Note that the *only* supported use for `register T name asm("reg")` is to force an `"r"` constraint to pick a certain register for an `asm("" :::)` Extended asm statement.  (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html used to imply stronger guarantees; that "only supported use" was added in the last few years and is probably significantly weaker than what they still do in practice.) Anyway, unless Clang documents stronger guarantees, it appears useless with `-fasm-blocks`.

Answer (score 1):

So, I had a look at MASM64, as suggested by Margaret Bloom, and I have to say it is generally cool to still have the option to generate assembly at all in MSVC. However, for my own case, I evaluated all the functions that are on my list to potentially rewrite in assembly.
Most of the are more complex functions (including calls to other functions; asserts; loops, jumps; ...), but only need a few specific commands to modify registers, or jmp to an address instead of a call. So, while I can use MASM for the simpler cases, I do want to have the option to code certain things with inline assembly, added to a normal c++-function. Luckily, I did find a way:

```
void interruptEntry(ExecutionStateJIT& state, Func pAddress)
{
    asm("mov rbx,%0;"
        :
        : "r" (&state)
        : "%rbx");

    auto* pTemp = *((void**)&state);
    asm("mov rdi,[%0];"
        :
        : "r" (pTemp)
        : "%rdi");

    pAddress();

    asm volatile("");
}
```

This compiles to my expected result:

```
 push        rdi  
 push        rbx  
 sub         rsp,28h  
 mov         rbx,rcx  
 mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  
 mov         rdi,qword ptr [rax]  
 call        rdx  
 nop  
 add         rsp,28h  
 pop         rbx  
 pop         rdi  
 ret
```

It does seem like using extended inline assembly is the way. Using the __asm-block somehow confused the compiler about what type of calls are being made - which is a shame, because I much preferred the syntax of __asm. Extended asm does allow me to tell the compiler which registers are modified - which is neat, because certain functions that I want to port, I explicitely do not want the modified registers to be restired. And I also can just use regular C++ intermixed, which is one of my requirements for certain operations.

I also had to make sure to include an empty volatile asm-block after the call, to prevent it from tail-calling (which would pop the registers before). There is this one nop, which I'm unsure about (it is not caused by the empty block directly; as if I write a volatile nop there, it will have two nops). But I kind of assume clang knows what it's doing here - otherwise, the minor cost of one nop is acceptable, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: This happens to work with this compiler / version, but there's no guarantee that a value left in a register by an `asm` statement will still be there at the start of another `asm` statement or compiler-generated code, especially when you actually are getting the compiler to generate some code that has to use registers.  It could just as easily have picked `mov rbx, [rcx]` / `call rbx` since it already had to save/restore that register because of the asm clobber declaration.

Comment: *Using the __asm-block somehow confused the compiler about what type of calls are being made* - A better way to describe that is that the compiler doesn't look inside asm blocks for anything except to figure out which registers were clobbered.  There are lots of things you might be hacking up with a `call` instruction, and it's not particularly well supported to make calls from inline asm.  It's a huge pain for the x86-64 System V calling convention, too, with GNU C extended asm (*[Calling printf in extended inline ASM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37502841)*)

Comment: You could write this in a way that discourages the compiler from stepping on your registers, by making those values needed in those registers after the `call` (as inputs to an empty `asm` statement), so the asm you want is the only efficient choice, which makes it a lot less likely that this will break in practice.  https://godbolt.org/z/9axEYYMrx works in GCC and clang (`-masm=ms` for GCC, and `-target x86_64-w64-windows-gnu` for Clang.)